# Workaround for lazy evaluation with date variable

Tags: r, lazy-evaluation

I am trying to use the `lazyeval` package and run into a problem. When I use certain variable names (e.g. date, mean) that exist as functions in R in my `data.frame`, `lazy` no longer works. So I had to fall back to using `substitute` instead. Is there a better workaround?

#### Functions

```
# this function has problems with certain variables
f_lazy <- function(data, variable){
  variable <- lazyeval::lazy(variable)
  lazyeval::lazy_eval(variable, data)
}
# these functions work
f_lazydots <- function(data, ...){
  variable <- lazyeval::lazy_dots(...)[[1]]
  lazyeval::lazy_eval(variable, data)
}
f_substitute <- function(data, variable){
  variable <- substitute(variable)
  eval(variable, data)
}
```

#### Sample data

```
data <- data.frame(x = 1, y = "a", date = Sys.Date(), mean = 1)
```

#### Examples

```
f_lazy(data, x)
## [1] 1
f_lazy(data, y)
## [1] a
## Levels: a
f_lazy(data, date)
## function () 
##   .Internal(date())
## <bytecode: 0x000000000cee1980>
##   <environment: namespace:base>
f_lazy(data, mean)
## function (x, ...) 
##   UseMethod("mean")
## <bytecode: 0x000000000bc87820>
##   <environment: namespace:base>
f_lazydots(data, date)
## [1] "2015-05-12"
f_lazydots(data, mean)
## [1] 1
f_substitute(data, date)
## [1] "2015-05-12"
f_substitute(data, mean)
## [1] 1
```

Comment: Name your variables more informatively. How about that solution?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, to write functions that can be reused I would not like to make restrictions on the column names of a `data.frame`. And in my opinion `date` is a reasonamly informative name. But I guess it would be sufficient if I could figure out if `lazy_eval` returns the column from the `data.frame` or something from an attached package. Then I could at least give an informative error message and tell users to rename their columns.